# How does the IoT reduce Bosch cooling costs?

Tags: hvac

I read [an article](https://internetofbusiness.com/bosch-canteen-singapore-iot-control-aircon/) recently from InternetOfBusiness.com which outlines how Bosch has been implementing remote controlling of their A/C systems. One thing, however, I fail to see in the article, and that is how *the IoT aspect **in particular*** helps save energy.  The article says,

> The engineers also set up a feedback panel at the canteen entrance to see if the IoT system was working; users could rate whether the temperature was too cold or hot for their liking.
>
> “Since we wanted to create a better experience for diners and lower energy consumption, we needed to check they were happy with the result.” He said.
>
> He added that results back from the system and the addition of ceiling fans meant that the company could increase the canteen thermostat from 24.5°C to around 26°C and the feedback from diners remained positive.
>
> “This temperature change almost halved the canteen’s cooling demands. We estimate that this will not only save around 4,000 Singapore dollars annually but reduce carbon dioxide emissions by more than eight tonnes,” said Staudacher.

How does the IoT make the air conditioning any more efficient?  Is it just that the people in the building can adjust it themselves, making the temperature not get as cold, consequently saving on energy, or what?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quite a biased article about IoT and energy saving.

From article:

> the addition of ceiling fans meant that the company could increase the canteen thermostat from 24.5°C to around 26°C and the feedback from diners remained positive.

They knew they can set the target temperature of cooler machine to higher (warmer) value when they adjusted the system using user feedback and IoT system data and algorithms. Using less effort on pushing cool air they saved money. Instead they used more fans.

Putting more fans, less cooling power and collecting feedback would have worked without IoT by wise guessing, but IoT proved its use on desicion making once again.

Why did I say biased?

By using IoT once a short period they came up an idea to save energy, nobody told adjusting temperature with IoT technology would save more than keeping fans all time on, at least nothing in that direction was said.

Comment: Keeping the fans on all the time would add heat energy to the system which the A/C would then need to remove.  Unless you're exchanging air with a colder exterior reserve, the cooling proved by a fan is largely subjective - things getting blown on get cooler, but the system overall gets hotter.  So spot fans where (and when) the people actually are may be most sensible.  The other possibility is that if the AC vent location is poor, the fans may help keep things more uniform and let it cool all the air in the room rather than overcool some of it.